# On Android, can I detect screen jank without looking at the screen?

Tags: android, performance, user-interface

I'm trying to use the output of systrace to detect janky scrolling during automated tests: I want to notice it early, without having to sit there watching.

I spent some time trying to fathom the trace, and found this ebook very helpful: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/high-performance-android/9781491913994/ch04.html

The most promising hypothesis was checking whether VSYNC-sf ever stopped ticking on phones displaying VSYNC-sf.

On other machines, SurfaceFlinger seems to be started by either HW_SYNC_0 or VSYNC (sometimes one or both of those VSYNCs stop) but SurfaceFlinger also seems to be involved with VsyncOn, which sometimes appears to keep track of whether there are activity buffers outstanding, and sometimes whether there are input events that need delivering. Confusingly, sometimes input events are delivered during half-second pauses when there's no surface flinger activity, no application drawing, and when even the VSYNC and HW_VSYNC signals decide to pause.

Does anyone know what's going on there?

Should I simply expect to see Surface Flinger always busy - not alternately busy and idle with each tick - and always aligned with one or other of the VSYNCs?

I also sometimes see SurfaceFlinger taking longer than a tick to complete its processing - is that the application's fault for having a very complicated display, or is it just something that happens because some queue isn't empty enough?

I'd prefer to miss a possible jank than claim to have found one which isn't there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Testing Display Performance](https://developer.android.com/preview/testing/performance.html) Lists how to use the new *framestats* command from *dumpsys* to get this type of information. It will provide information on what frames you've missed, and how many of them you've missed.

It's also worth noting that SurfaceFlinger isn't always busy. It's only active when part of the screen needs to be updated. If nothing on the screen needs updating, then no new rendering occurs, and such, SurfaceFlinger should be idle.

You can get a bigger-picture view of the Android rendering pipeline with the [Rendering Performance 101](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HXQhu6qfTVU&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9CBxr3BVjPTPoDPLdPIFCE&index=33) video from [Android Performance Patterns](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9CBxr3BVjPTPoDPLdPIFCE).

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful stuff. Unfortunately, I'm swamped by lots of other stuff at the moment, but hopefully I'll get back to this!